# Datatable takes more time to load after first time loaded in client side

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using datatables js for my application, when i load 100000 records at first time it takes 30 sec average time but after first time it takes twice the time as first, searched internet for this but i could not find proper solution.

Any idea?

Comment: it is because when you get the records in 30 sec for the first time , and then again when you call for more records then those 30 sec records also comes . Why don't you call it like 10 records at a time not 100000 in bulk . There is a way of doing this in ASP.NET `take()` and `skip()` . I don't know which platform you are using ?

Comment: If you are using server-side and does not want to load all data, you can pipeline your datatable to avoid loading of all records. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Comment: @TusharRaj how to avoid those previous 30 sec records

Comment: @jorrin need help in client side

Comment: @NandhaKumar yes, you can use pipelining to cache the number of pages in the table and only load some number of items making the loading faster.